# Publishing page after reference implementation

Tags: 2013, publishing, dxa

I have recently got reference implementation done on Tridion 2013. I have published a page. where can i access the page that i have published? i can access the example site and i have also checked the root folder but i could not find the published page. Please help me with this.

http://localhost:82
Loads the Homepage of example site.

http://localhost:82/sample
Says

> **Page Not Found**
>  The page you were looking for cannot be
>   found. This page may have been moved. We apologize for any
>   inconvenience.
>  in the example site.

http://localhost:82/sample/SamplePage
Says

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: Can you put in your question the full URL you are using for a working page (eg the home page) and that for the page which is not working?

Comment: Try changing the filename of your page to index, republishing it and hitting the url localhost:82/sample

Comment: Says "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond "

Comment: It sounds like you have some connection issues not related to the DXA

Comment: What kind of connection issues. but it is loading the Home page of example site right?

Comment: What happens if you make a copy of the homepage in your sample directory and access that - does it work? If so then it must be something to do with something on your sample page - what content is on there? Is there any custom view or controller code used?

Comment: It is just rendering a component. I was able to preview the sample page and it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support Will Price. I found the reason why the page can't load. I will post it in the answer. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The Reference Implementation has an MVC web application which does not load pages from the file system, but rather from the broker database. Hence you will not find your, or any of the example site pages in the root or any other folder. You should be able to access the page by entering the URL you used when creating the page (the filename). What do you mean when you say you can access the example site? Do you see the example homepage and other pages when browsing? If these pages are working then you should not have any problems seeing your page, provided that it has been published successfully.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I can see the example homepage when browsing, but i cannot open the page that i have created and published. The page i published is a different structure group but not the structure group of the example site, is that a problem?

Comment: That shouldnt be a problem. What directory name did you use when you created the structure group? The URL to browse the page should be this followed by the page filename...

Comment: The directory name is sample. and the structure group is child of "home" structure group(which is created by reference implementation).

Comment: Then you should be able to access the page with the URL /sample/whatever-your-page-filename-is

Comment: The page says. "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: Check the STRI logfile (by default `C:\Temp\Site.log`) for any errors logged by STRI. If there are no errors in there, change the log level to Debug and retry, it should give an idea whether your request reaches STRI or gets stopped somewhere earlier. An IIS Failed Request Log can also provide more insight in where the failure originates.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the new (in my case sample) structure group to check the inherit from parent solved the problem. I can see the pages now.

Comment: `Inherit from Parent` on the Structure Group, sets the default Page Template for each new Page you create, and similair `Inherit from Parent` on the Page will set its Page Template to that from the Structure group definition. So it sounds to me like your issue was caused by using a wrong Page Template for your Page (perhaps you used the Redirect Page Template?